# How would I get a specific portion of a regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to get the domain name of a URL. I could run a series of if statements that check what the url contains, but ideally I'd use a regex.

The following regex `^[^.]*:[\/]{0,2}[w]{0,3}[.]{0,1}[\w]*.[\w\W]*$` does enough of what I want.

This applies for:
`https://www.google.com`
`http://www.google.com`
`www.google.com`

Now I just want to get `google.com` from this regex, but unsure how to do that.

Comment: Learn about [capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Comment: The exact syntax depends on what language you're using but you put the portion you want in a group using brackets. `a(b)c` will match `abc` and return `b` as the value of the first group.

Comment: @DomWeldon It is tagged »javascript«, so the language is defined…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to the comment of [@PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1)

`RegExp.prototype.exec()` ([mdn-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)) gives you a result array, where each index corresponds to the »capturing groups« in your expression:

```
var
  input = 'Hello',
  finder = /^(H)ell(o)/m,
  match = finder.exec(input);

console.log(match) // ["Hello", "H", "o"]
```

Index `0` is the whole match, each following item is the result of the capturing groups, which are established by `(…)` in the regular expression and ordered from left to right in appearance in the expression.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly,

Try this `^([^.]*:[\/]{0,2}[w]{0,3}[.]{0,1}){0,1}[\w]*.[\w\W]*$`

To Explain:

I decided to group the part that looks for the protocol and the www part `[^.]*:[\/]{0,2}[w]{0,3}[.]{0,1}`, and made it optional by grouping it together by wrapping it in parenthesis `(...)` and adding a 0 or 1 times clause for the whole group `{0,1}`

Comment: your regex doesn't work, it's accepting basically anything, e.g. `https:a123zsdca.sdkfj//google.com`

Comment: `^([^.]*:[\/]{0,2}[w]{0,3}[.]{0,1}){0,1}[\w]*.[a-zA-Z]*$` try that one. However, if you're wanting to do url matching, this has a few flaws i can see off the bat. That being said, according to your spec, that should work.

Comment: That does not work either. It literally accepts `a112z`. But anyway my regex is fine for my purposes, and I will be using capturing groups.

Comment: Right, but that was never part of your spec. The regex you provided matches on anything beginning with `http://www.` it can be, as you stated above `http://www.a123zsdca.sdkfj//google.com`. If you've found a way that suits you, then I'm glad. I won't pretend to know what you need this for, but like I said above, there are a lot of holes in the regex you provided if your intended purpose is url matching.

Comment: I specified the purpose of the regex is to access the domain name, e.g. google.com, facebook.com, etc and get rid of the prefix and suffix, which would be https://, http://. I don't care about what's after domain name, since anything after the period is scrubbed. I simply need the prefix to function correctly, and then capture everything leading up to the first space, and I can now do that. Thanks for the suggestions though.